# UNIX copy lines to new file IF one column matches AND another has a value below 5x10^-8

Tags: unix, copy, conditional-statements, line

Similar question to many previous ones (including mine) but I can't find the solution. This is purely a syntax error and I cannot figure out how to make it work.

I have two files in Unix. In file1 I have 5 columns and about 6000 rows. I am trying to match rows in file2 to rows in file1 IF column 1 matches exactly AND if the value in row 5 of file1 is less than 0.00000005 for said row.

file1:

```
SNPs    Context Intergenic  Risk Allele Frequency   p-Value
rs9747992   Intergenic  1   0.086   2.00E-07
rs2059865   Intron  0   0.235   3.00E-07
rs117020818 Intergenic  1   0.046   7.00E-07
rs1074145   Intergenic  1   0.162   4.00E-09
```

file2:

```
snpid hg18chr bp a1 a2 zscore pval CEUmaf
rs3131972   1   742584  A   G   0.289   0.7726  .
rs3131969   1   744045  A   G   0.393   0.6946  .
rs3131967   1   744197  T   C   0.443   0.658   .
rs1048488   1   750775  T   C   -0.289  0.7726  .
```

I can do the first part BUT it keeps outputting a file that is larger than the first two. I am unsure if this is a real result file or just full of duplicates? I also cannot do the 'less than' command. I have tried putting it into the command as a second pattern and also piping it, as below:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}{if ($1 in a) {print $0}}' file1 file2 > output | awk '{if (a[$5] < 0.00000005)}'
```

and

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}{if ($1 in a && $5 < 0.00000005)} {print $0}}' file1 file2 > output
```

Both times it's giving me the same size file which is much larger than either file1 or file2. If you want examples of the tables please just say.

Tentative solution:

A tentative solution I am using is to just make a new file containing only lines from file1 which have that <0.00000005 value. This works though I would like to know my original answer for posterity.

```
awk '$5<=0.00000005' file1 > file11
```

Comment: Your description makes me think that you want to filter on the values in `file2`, but you are using `FNR==NR` to load the `file1` into the search-target array. Try changing the tail-end of your 2nd cmd to `file2 file1 > output`. Good luck.

Comment: (Fixed formatting problems, read this first;-) ). In your 1st cmd, `...file1 file2 > output | awk ...` is a shell non-sequitor. Nothing will happen with the code `|awk ...`. You've already captured all the printed output with `>output`. Your 2nd solution seems very close. will look at this for a few mins

Comment: Also, you need to learn to think with scale. You can pose this question with a 4 column data set, get that to work correctly, **and then** just change the `$1, $4` (or what ever) references back to $22 and $28 when you think the smaller test case is working correctly. Can you edit your question to deal with that? Add 3-4 lines of data for both files and  you'll have a solution from numerous eager helpers ;-) Good luck.

Comment: Your second awk script has 0.0000005 (6 zeros) and it should be 0.00000005 (7 zeros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comments above, if you're using file2 as a filter list, you need to load it into the `a[]` array.

I've made up a small sample of how that works, the test for `$28 < .000005` should be easy to add as you have it in your code.

With file **data1**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 3 4 5 6 7 8
4 5 8 7 8 9 10
```

and file **searchList**

```
3
```

Then

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=$0;next}
     FNR!=NR{ if ($2 in a) print $0}
     #dbg END{for (x in a) print "x="x " a[x]=" a[x]
}' searchList data1
```

gives output

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

**edit** Per our conversation in comments, my best guess without seeing your required output would be

I've added an extra record in file1 so there can be match

```
rs3131972   Intergenic  1   0.086   2.00E-07


awk '( FNR==NR && (sprintf("%.07f",$5) < .000000005) ) {
        a[$1]=$0
        #dbg print "a["$1"]="a[$1]
        next
    } 
    FNR!=NR{ 
        #dbg print "$1="$1 
        if ($1 in a)print "Matched:" $0
    }' file1 file2
```

The output is now

```
Matched:rs3131972   1   742584  A   G   0.289   0.7726  .
```

IHTH

Comment: Hey Shellter. File 1 is the pattern containing file that I want to use to filter out file2 (sorry for being unclear).

I want to grab the rows from file2 which match a row in file1 with a pval < 0.00000005. I edited it like you recommended. Will your method here still be useful?

Comment: hmm. now I see that you're "doubling-back" to compare from the sourceList (`file1`) for the `.0000005` value. I would only put values in `a[]` if that condition is true. ALSO, please add your expected output from that set of inputs.

Comment: The output should look exactly the same as file2, just containing fewer lines (as they should be filtered by file1). Your command here results in all the lines from file2 being printed into the output file.

Comment: That's funny, I setup your files, and when I ran my code, I didn't get any output. Are you asking that the code can compare a string value like (in first line of file1) `2.00E-07` to `.00000002`without converting it to a comparable format?

Comment: Hm... and I don't see any of the values from file1.$1 in file2.$1. See my update for comparing `2.00E-07` to `.00000002` type values (using sprintf).

Comment: And, per your previous question, be sure to filter your files with `dos2unix`. Good luck.

Comment: The issue was tab delimiting. I added -F $'\t' on the begin line and got a result. I'll answer with the successful code. Thank you for your time shellter.

Comment: OK, glad that helped. Good luck and please start including exact expected output as part of your question. It eliminates a whole class of problems ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Shellter's answer is good. Mine is more about what you did wrong. Your first attempt

```
> awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}{if ($1 in a) {print $0}}
      ' file1 file2 > output | awk '{if (a[$5] < 0.00000005)}'
```

fails because your pipeline is wrong. You need to pipe `awk | awk > output` not `awk >output | awk`. The latter will receive no input and produce no output from the last step of the pipeline. Also, the second Awk instance has no knowledge of the variables you used in the first.

Furthermore, you seem to have a recurring problem with spurious braces in Awk.  The general syntax is `awk` "*condition<sub>1</sub>* `{` *action<sub>1</sub>* `}` *condition<sub>2</sub>* `{`  *action<sub>2</sub>* `}`..." where you can omit a *condition* to do an *action* unconditionally, or omit the *action* part (with the braces) to perform the default action `{ print $0 }`.  But here, you have only an action, which is however actually a condition, with no side effects such as printing anything.  You want to remove the braces and the `if` wrapper.

So you need

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}{if ($1 in a) {print $0}}' file1 file2 |
awk '$5 < 0.00000005' >output
```

which (in accordance with the rules for omitting a condition or an action, and with some refactoring) can be much simplified to

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}
    $1 in a' file1 file2 |
awk '$5 < 0.00000005' >output
```

Your second attempt is closer;

```
> awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}
    {if ($1 in a && $5 < 0.00000005)} {print $0}}' file1 file2 > output
```

but again, you have too many brackets. The closing brace after the `if` ruins it all! So you have effectively "if (condition)" then nothing (maybe this should be a syntax error!), followed by a new block with an unconditional `print`. But overall, this is much better.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}
    {if ($1 in a && $5 < 0.00000005) print $0}' file1 file2 > output
```

which of course can be simplified to

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}
     ($1 in a) && $5 < 0.00000005' file1 file2 > output
```

Comment: I see now that I missed that the condition would be applied against the first file, but since you already got that covered, I'll just leave it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Slowly getting a handle on UNIX.

Answer (score 0):

Answer that worked based on Shellters assistance.

```
awk -F $'\t' 'NR==FNR{if ($5 < 0.00000005){a[$1]=$0}} NR!=FNR{if ($1 in a) print $0}' file1 file2 > output
```

Thanks